# Catching CharConversionException in Spring Boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, exception, jwt

I have a typical JWT authentication process on my app. I am able to catch most of the token errors, but when the user sends a bad bearer token (ex. `ads.asd.d`), `CharConversionException` is being thrown.

```
java.io.CharConversionException: Not an ISO 8859-1 character: [�]
```

The issue is that I can't catch it. I am getting this error.

```
exception java.io.CharConversionException is never thrown in body of corresponding try statement
```

**Filter class:**

```
public class JwtRequestFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

    @Autowired
    private MyUserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    private JwtUtil jwtUtil;

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws ServletException, IOException, MalformedJwtException, CharConversionException {

        final String authorizationHeader = request.getHeader("Authorization");

        String username = null;
        String jwt = null;

        try {
            if (authorizationHeader != null && authorizationHeader.startsWith("Bearer ")) {
                jwt = authorizationHeader.substring(7);
                username = jwtUtil.extractUsername(jwt);
            }
        } catch (MalformedJwtException e) {
            response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED);
            return;
        } catch (CharConversionException e) {
            response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED);
            return;
        }

        ...

        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    }
```

Any idea on how I can catch that exception?

Comment: Why aren't you using the one built into Spring/Spring Boot?

Comment: @SledgeHammer The filter method?